# GCD serial queue and race condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading

I have two methods which run on a serial queue. Each method return a copy of some class. I'm trying to achieve thread safety solution while also mainting data integrity.

for example:

```
-(Users *) getAllUsers
{ 
       __block copiedUsers;
       dispatch_sync(_backgroundQueue, ^{
            copiedUsers = [self.users copy]; // return copy object to calling thread.  
       });
       return copiedUsers;
}

-(Orders *) getAllOrders
{ 
       __block copiedOrders;
       dispatch_sync(_backgroundQueue, ^{
            copiedOrders = [self.Orders copy]; // return copy object to calling thread.
       });
       return copiedOrders;
}
```

In addition to this two methods, I have a worker class that add/remove users and orders, all done via a serial queue `backgroundQueue`.

If in the main thread I call `getAllUsers` and then `getAllOrders` right after the other my data integrity isn't safe because between the two calls the worker class might have changed the model.

my question is how can I make to the caller a nice interface that allows multiple methods to run atomically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model is only updated from `backgroundQueue` serial queue.
Client talks to model via a method that receives a block that runs in the background queue.

In addition, not to freeze main thread, I create another queue and run a block that talks with the gateway method.

P.S - attention that `dispatch_sync` is called only in `runBlockAndGetNeededDataSafely` to avoid deadlocks.

Code sample:

aViewController.m

```
ManagerClass *m = [ManagerClass new];    
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create("funnelQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_block_t block_q = ^{
    __Users *users;
    __Orders *orders;
    [manager runBlockAndGetNeededDataSafely:^
     {
            users  = [manager getUsers];
            orders = [manager getOrders];
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
          ^{
               // got data safely - no thread issues, copied objects. update UI!
               [self refreshViewWithUsers:users 
                                  orders:orders];
           });
     }];
}
dispatch_async(q, block_q);
```

Manager.m implementation:

```
-(void) runBlockInBackground:(dispatch_block_t) block
{
    dispatch_sync(self.backgroundQueue, block); 
}
 -(Users *) getAllUsers
 { 
       return [self.users copy];
 }

 -(Orders *) getAllOrders
 {  
       return [self.Orders copy];
 }
```

Comment: I have edit your answer for easier discussion. The code inside `block_q` is queuing a `task` to the `backgroundQueue` and then notify the main thread. You will get the update signal before the `orders` and `users` updated. I think your code will work properly if you have a `dispatch_semaphore_t` in the `block_q` and wait until `runBlockAndGetNeededDataSafely` is finished.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I approved it.  What update signal you mean? And why would I need dispatch_semaphore_t?

Comment: The update signal is `refreshViewWithUsers`. Because it will execute the `refreshViewWithUsers` no matter what the `runBlockAndGetNeededDataSafely` is finished or not

Comment: Updated answer, had a small mistake, please see updated answer.

Comment: I also make a mistake in my first comment. The problem is your `getAllOrders` and `getAllUsers`. It still returns immediately. You still need a way to wait until all of data is ready in the `backgroundQueue`.

Comment: re-editing answer, in current sample there will be a deadlock.

Comment: I don't see any problems with current implementation. do you?

Comment: It is easy to avoid the deadlock by checking if the code is execute in the same queue. Your code still doesn't work because the `getAllOrders` and `getAllOrders` still return immediately. They still don't wait until the other data is ready.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `users` and `orders` is asynchronously updated. There is a case that you are querying `users` while `orders` is updating and you still return un-finish updated `orders` with the updated `users`

Comment: sahara108, all updating is being performed in the `backgroundQueue` which is a serial queue, meaning such scenario can't happen.

Comment: You are right. So this code will work perfectly. Be careful to update your data synchronously in `backgroundQueue`. It is often to update the data with something like this `[self downloadData:^(NSData *result, NSError *error){self.users = ....};` and you will get the case as I mentioned.

Comment: I'm using AFNetworking to fetch data from the network. In there I set the completionQueue to `backgroundQueue` which mean that it'll simply `dispatch_async` to `backgroundQueue` which shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: sahara108, could you please elaborate your strategy on how to prevent deadlock by checking which is the current running queue?

Comment: Are your sure? Who will trigger the `backgroundQueue` first? Imagine the network is very slow and AFNetworking will update data after 5 ~ 10s. Are you sure you will not request `data` before the network is completed.

Comment: About checking the current queue, I will post another answer because it is too long for comment

Comment: sahara108, The data model is always changing, not only due to pulling request, but also due to push changes I receive from the server. What's important for me is that I get the whole data atomically when the user asks for it. So in the sense, this scenario doesn't worry me.

Comment: If you say so, your code will be good. I an also enlightened by the way you solve the problem. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about how to checking the current queue:
First when you create the queue, give it a tag:

```
static void* queueTag = &queueTag;
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("a queue", 0);
dispatch_queue_set_specific(queue, queueTag, queueTag, NULL);
```

and then run a block like this:

```
-(void)runBlock:(void(^)()) block
{
    if (dispatch_get_specific(queueTag) != NULL) {
        block();
    }else {
        dispatch_async(self.queue, block);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat. Are you sure there's no problem using this? Because that's is really an awesome way to prevent deadlocks :-)

Comment: That's sweet. I'll start using it as well, this can be very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work. I suggest to use completion callback. You should have an option to know when the worker finish his job to return to value.

```
- (void)waitForCompletion:(BOOL*)conditions length:(int)len timeOut:(NSInteger)timeoutSecs {
    NSDate *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeoutSecs];
    BOOL done = YES;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        done = done & *(conditions+i);
    }
    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeoutDate];
        if([timeoutDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0)
            break;

        //update done
        done = YES;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            done = done & *(conditions+i);
        }
    } while (!done);
}


-(void) getAllUsers:(void(^)(User* user, NSError* error))completion
{
    dispatch_async(_backgroundQueue, ^{
        BOOL condition[2] = [self.userCondition, self.orderCondition];
        [self waitForCompletion: &condition[0] length:2 timeOut:60];
        if (completion) {
            completion([self.users copy], nil);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, updated question with correct implementation.

Comment: Your example will return a pointer immediately and change its value later on. You don't when the change occurs so that it is hard if you need to update UI.

Comment: Yes, it's better for get methods to run synchronously, as I've updated in my question.

Comment: Ok. Then beware that you can freeze the main thread. And also, it may occur the dead lock if you call this method in the same `_backgroundQueue`.

Comment: sahara108, fully aware of this, thanks for the warning. I'll even update the question to handle deadlock. :-)

Comment: sahara108, thanks for the answer. However, your answer doesn't handle syntonisation between users and orders. Moreover, I have no need for timing here.

Comment: You will check it via `finishJob` option. For example, when you finish update users and order, set `finishJob = true`. I just add the timeout to be sure the method is alway call back. You can ignore it as well.

Comment: It looks like a design problem. Synchronization the way you are thinking won't work here. Users and Orders together represent one state of system. You have to fetch them together as separate but synchronized background processes. What I mean is when self.users is updated at the same time self.orders should also get updated. You have to wait for both of the fetch to finish before you update the models. This ways if one fetch has finished while the other is still on going, you will end up returning the the old models copy because you don't update them separately but in one shot.

Comment: sahara108, this will over complicate the worker as there can be many different connection between objects.

Comment: Agree. I just make a little change that will help the worker not to be complicate.

Comment: Please see my answer below. What do you think?